# Creating half circle buttons with inward shadow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a button that looks like this : 
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7wWF.png)

But the closest thing I managed to do is looks like this : 
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXYIl.png)

Here's the CSS for the one I created :

```
body section div div.left-arrow
height:45px;
position:absolute;
width:58px;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
background:#efeeee;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 53px -25px rgba(0,0,0,1),0px 10px 14px -0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 53px -25px rgba(0,0,0,1),0px 10px 14px -0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 53px -25px rgba(0,0,0,1),0px 10px 14px -0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
margin-left: 860px;
margin-top: 206px;
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can make it look more like the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not working they way you want it to because when you rotate an object the CSS properties are still applied as if the object was not rotated. So if you make the half circle without the rotating it (which makes more sense to do it this way) i think the effect works better. Here's what I used.

```
.arrow {
    background: #efeeee;
    height: 45px;
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
    box-shadow: inset 4px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

I tried to simplify the code so i removed the -moz, -webkit code which you can add back in. [You can see a js.fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ss1bocpy/1/). Hope thats more of what you are a looking for. BTW is that your real name?

Comment: Looks a lot better than what I did, thank you. And no, that is obviously not my real name.

Comment: @GilbertBoner with a few more shadows, it can look closer http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWLjyr or http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNxBza

Comment: @GilbertBoner haha ok fair enough. Glad I was able to help you out